# Simple button click counter using PHP, AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: php

I simply just want to count the clicks of a button and save the amount of clicks to a text file, but I cannot seem to get this code to work. It does not save the amount of clicks.

In the HTML file I have a button that runs the JavaScript using `onClick`:

```
function do() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
              xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else 
    {
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
              var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              }
            xhr.open('GET','count.php',false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
                    while(results.hasChildNodes()) {
                        results.removeChild(results.lastChild);
                    }
                    results.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
    }
```

In the PHP file we called, we have the following code:

```
<?php

    $clicks = file_get_contents("clicks.txt");
    $clicks++;

    $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");

    while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
        usleep(500000); // Delay half a second
    }

    fwrite($fp, $clicks);
    fclose($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

?>
```

Can you help me to find the problem in my code?
How would I read the text file in another HTML page?
(Just show the information of the text file.)

Comment: What is the problem in your code?

Comment: Can you access your PHP file directly in your browser, and see what happens?

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Tried now! It worked! Increases the amount in the text file. The problem might be in the JavaScript.

Comment: In case `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` should be used, the actual request to `count.php` is never executed because the relevant code is only present in the scope of `else`. Move the remaining code outside the `if` statement

Comment: I am kinda new to this. Can you show me?

Comment: Nice race condition... if you have multiple people hitting this 'counter' at the same time, you ARE going to lose clicks. Why aren't you using a database for this?

Comment: No, I delay it if it is in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `PHP` page is functioning properly, the following should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

function getXMLHttp()
{
  var xmlHttp
  try
  {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      try
      {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert("AJAX not supported.")
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "count.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
        </script>
        <input type='button' onclick='MakeRequest();' value='Button'/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id='ResponseDiv'>
            Count
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, proper error handling is important, doing `AJAX` requests while `AJAX` is not supported makes absolutely no sense and might cause errors.

Comment: If Ajax dose not work, I do not want to disturb the user. Is that OK to just remove it?

Comment: Only remove the `alert("AJAX not supported.")` line, then the user won't be disturbed in case `AJAX` is not available. Don't touch the `try` statements, they are required for proper error handling.

Comment: Thanks. They don't have to know if their click is not counted - agree? What should I do if I do not want to show the count on this page - just count clicks - but show it on another page?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note here on the php side.

1) You're opening the file with w+ which is for writing and reading what you've wrote. This also truncates your file BEFORE your lock is in place.

2) Your lock will cause parallel read and writes to fail. This can set $clicks to false and possibly wipe out your counter if the file is unlocked before fopen gets called.

3) You are not correctly releasing your lock because you close the handle while the lock is active. If this happens to be a long running script the lock will not be released until the script terminates.

This should solve all of those problems.

```
<?php

$fp = false;
// Open file for reading, then writing
while ( ($fp=fopen('clicks.txt','r+'))===false ) {
    usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
}
// Obtain lock
while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
    usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
}
// Read Clicks
$clicks = trim(fread($fp,1024));
// Add click
$clicks++;
// Empty file
ftruncate($fp,0);
// Write clicks
fwrite($fp, $clicks);
// Release Lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
// Release handle
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: How do I show the content of the text file in a complete diffrent web page?

Comment: Just open the file as read only (r), use a read lock instead of an exclusive lock so this script can't block you in the middle of a read. You should put the fopen and flock calls in a loop since you are locking it with a different script. This sort of thing is a LOT easier if you just used a database. :)

Comment: Okay. I am going to when I get a server. I have already written the XML request thingy... do I just use that and reprogram my PHP to save it to a server?