# php onclick to retrieve dataset

Tags: php, hyperlink, dataset

I have a list of values that upon hyperlink 'onclick' will display the associated recordset in an array below.

Through PHP, I have the dataset of connected table values working. Now I need to link that dataset to the onclick event.

Through my research there are a few ways I can go about this: iFrames (seems not recommended); JSON/AJAX (languages which I do not know and none of my other data uses this construct, but is it possible to use straight PHP?);

$_GET variable with a related function seems to be the way to go though am struggling to get the right syntax to create a response. Will this be using a filter function?

essentially: $row_artistrecordset['artist'] = $row_getartists['artist']. If I can base the code on this match construct it will hopefully be versatile enough for use in other pages.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$query_artistrecordset = "SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY artist ASC";
$artistrecordset = mysql_query($query_artistrecordset, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
$row_artistrecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($artistrecordset);
$totalRows_artistrecordset = mysql_num_rows($artistrecordset);
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>artistindex</title>
  <link href="exhibitstyles/exhibitstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>    
 <?php include_once("exhibitstyles/header.php");?> 
 <div id="singlemid" class="paragraph" style="text-align:center"> 
<div id="artistlist">
<?php do { ?>
<a href=javascript:function_$_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]);>; title="artistlink" class="list"><?php echo $row_artistrecordset['artist']; ?></a>&nbsp;|
<?php } while ($row_artistrecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($artistrecordset)); ?>
</div>
<br />    
<div id="searchresults">

function_$_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]) {
$.post("artistindex.php",'v=.$row_getartists['artist'].' + value, function $_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]) {
      $query_getartists.html().trigger("create");
});
}

<?php
mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
 echo <a href=javascript:function_$_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]);>.$row_getartists['artist'].;
 $query_getartists = "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE artist = '".$row_artistrecordset['artist']."' ORDER BY artist ASC";
 $getartists = mysql_query($query_getartists, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row_getartists = mysql_fetch_assoc($getartists)) {              
                echo $row_getartists['artist'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getartists['website'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getartists['artist_statement'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getartists['image'], "<br>";
 $artistlink = $row_getartists['artist'];
 $query_getseries = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE artist='$artistlink' ORDER BY exhibition ASC";
 $getseries = mysql_query($query_getseries, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row_getseries = mysql_fetch_assoc($getseries)) {
                echo $row_getseries['series'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getseries['exhibition'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getseries['series_statement'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getseries['image'], "<br>";
 $serieslink = $row_getseries['series'];
 $query_getpieces = "SELECT * FROM pieces WHERE series='$serieslink'";
 $getpieces = mysql_query($query_getpieces, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row_getpieces = mysql_fetch_assoc($getpieces)) {
                echo $row_getpieces['piece'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getpieces['category'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getpieces['dimensions'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getpieces['price'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getpieces['description'], "<br>";
                echo $row_getpieces['image'], "<br>";
      }
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($getartists);

mysql_free_result($getseries);

mysql_free_result($getpieces);
      }
?>
```

Comment: If I am doing this entirely wrong, please tell me. Other questions I have found trying to achieve a similar goal have not been answered either so it is hard to know what is wrong with this logic.

Comment: "onclick" defines a Javascript function that will execute when the element is clicked. To do something such as what you want will require either changing to another PHP script which will generate the new page or much nicer an AJAX call which will refresh the data on the page without reloading it. Check out jQuery for a truly easy way to use AJAX.

Comment: Right! So I am doing this wrong and using js unwittingly...thankyou! that is what I needed to know!

Comment: @mlewis54 o dear this is now even deeper as I don't quite understand the jquery language. not sure where to begin so would be able to explain and give pointers as to where and how? For example, is my while loop already js language within a php block?

Comment: @sarah369 I'm curious. Is your `<a href="#"onclick=` working? I've tried that method and it didn't work for me. I use something along the line of `<a href="javascript:function();">Link</a>`.

Comment: The onclick is not working, I will try this and when I do do I need to echo it within the array set in the same way? or does that change aswell? I still have the confusing syntax error in my echo link that is not helping with the test!: echo <a href="javascript:function(artistindex.php?$_GET[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]);">.$row_getartists['artist'].;

Comment: @sarah369 My link example was just that, an example. The `function` part is the name of your actual function, so it would translate to `<a href="javascript:function_name();">Link</a>`. You're obviously trying to use `Ajax`, am I correct? And when you answer me, could you add the `@` symbol in front of my name, just so I know? Now, if you're not using Ajax, then why use `onclick`, when you can just link directly to your query?

Comment: @Fred so: <a href=javascript:function_$_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]);> is this correct? then how do I link it to the dataset?

Comment: @sarah369 No. Here's a quick example on using an inline Javascript function. For example: In my HTML, I have `<a href="javascript:MakeRequest();">Link</a>` then in my `JS` I have `function MakeRequest() { // code executes here }`. When you click on the `href`, it calls the `MakeRequest` function then from there, executes what's inside that function. That's basically how this works.

Comment: @sarah369 Here's a link on SO that you can study http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160777/simple-button-click-counter-using-php-ajax-and-javascript and will show you the basic principles of calling a function in order to execute stuff.

Comment: @Fred what is the exact makerequest based on my data? I am getting confused and think I will now border on applying contradicting code...

Comment: @sarah369 Have a look at the link I gave you above, and on that page search for `MakeRequest()`. There should be a few instances that will show up, and you will see how functions work and get called. That is the best explanation I can give you, while it being a visual one on that page. Here is the link again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160777/simple-button-click-counter-using-php-ajax-and-javascript

Comment: @sarah369 Inside that page, you will notice `xmlHttp.open("GET", "count.php", true);` The `count.php` is only an example file. You will have your database insertion/retrieval code inside that file, where you can change it from `count.php` to `retrieve.php` as an example. I'm not an SQL guy, so I am unsure as to how to put it all together for you.

Comment: @Fred I don't think do have a count...I will place the pages code in full above...my brain has exploded

Comment: @sarah369 It was only an example. The `count` part, you will need to change/delete all the info in `count` and replace it with your code. If this is too much right now, take a break and come back to it at a later time; it works ;-)

Comment: @Fred thankyou for your help. I don't think I am capable of resolving this at the moment, I think I need to start all over again as I am just making Frankenstein code.

Comment: @sarah369 You're welcome. I will say this, the `function_$_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']])` is not right at all. A total rewrite would be the way to go, however I suggest you read up on Ajax first if that's the route you choose to follow, and finding some working examples. I'm sure you'll find something on SO, and Googling. All the best, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You want an action to take place when the user clicks something. Let's say you have a table of values and you want to get further information about a value. The html might look like this:

```
<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=30% valign=top><span onclick="alert('Value 1 was clicked');">1</span></td>
<td width=70% valign=top>Description of Value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=30% valign=top><span onclick="alert('Value 2 was clicked');">1</span></td>
<td width=70% valign=top>Description of Value 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What will happen here is that the javascript alert() function will be called when you click on either of the two leftmost columns of the table.

You could also pass the information to your own script as in:

```
    <script>
    function myOwnAlert(value) {
         alert(value);
    }
    </script>
<div id="myTable">
    <table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
    <td width=30% valign=top><span onclick="myOwnAlert('Value 1 was clicked');">1</span></td>
    <td width=70% valign=top>Description of Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width=30% valign=top><span onclick="myOwnAlert('Value 2 was clicked');">1</span></td>
    <td width=70% valign=top>Description of Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The net effect is the same, a message was displayed. However, you could also update the table dynamically using jQuery. There are a number of tutorials on jQuery available online. You will basically wind up with a javascript function such as:

```
<script>
function myOwnAlert(value) {
    $.post("getnewtable.php",'v=' + value, function(data) {
          $("#myTable").html().trigger("create");
    });
}
</script>
```

This will result in the contents of your table being replaced with the output of the your getnewtable.php script.

Note: This is not meant to be a prime example of using either HTML or jQuery -- just a very mini-tutorial.

Comment: ok, so focusing on the last example you gave do I place this as the href"" and is this correct:   function_$_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]) {
    $.post("artistindex.php",'v=.$row_getartists['artist'].' + value, function $_GET(artistindex.php?[$row_artistrecordset['artist']]) {
          $query_getartists.html().trigger("create");
    });

Comment: I thought that such a 'if' 'else' construct was php? I am confused as to the line between what is php and what is java...

Comment: If you're going to use javascript I would not use an href, that's why I surrounded the values with <span></nospan> tags. it would be more like: function getArtistIndex(v) { then the $.post call) } The onclick call triggers your javascript function which then makes a call to a php script. If/else constructs appear in many languages. The code between <script> and </script> tags is javascript (not java). There is no PHP in my example, just javascript and HTML.